# I have to create an application where I need to use threads, but they don't work as they should

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I have this code where every person is represented by a special Thread that is instantiated with random ticket data and every 5 seconds a FestivalStatisticsThread wakes up and reads the new data from the gate and generates statistics (how many people have enterd and with what type of ticket).

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        FestivalGate gate = new FestivalGate();
        FestivalAttendeeThread festivalAttendee;
        FestivalStatisticsThread statsThread = new FestivalStatisticsThread(gate);
        TicketType ticketType;
        for (int i = 1; i < 85_000; i++) {
            ticketType = TicketType.randomTicket();
            festivalAttendee = new FestivalAttendeeThread(ticketType, gate);
            festivalAttendee.start();
            festivalAttendee.join();

        }

        statsThread.start();

        System.out.println(gate.getValidatedTickets().size());

    }
}
```

The problem is that I did not find a way to wake up that thread every 5 second and generate statisitics, the only way I could do it is by generating the statistics only once at the end
The second problem is that I should use join after I start the festivalAttendee thread, otherwise the list where I store the ticket types doesn't store all of them, although is synchronized.

I will also leave here the code that does the inner workings of my code:

```
public class FestivalGate {
    private List<TicketType> validatedTickets = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
    public List<TicketType> getValidatedTickets() {
        return validatedTickets;
    }

}
```

---

```
public class FestivalAttendeeThread extends Thread {

    TicketType ticketType;
    FestivalGate festivalGate;

    public FestivalAttendeeThread(TicketType ticketType, FestivalGate festivalGate) {
        this.ticketType = ticketType;
        this.festivalGate = festivalGate;
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void run() {
        this.festivalGate.getValidatedTickets().add(ticketType);
    }

}
```

---

```
public class FestivalStatisticsThread extends Thread {

    private int NR_OF_FULL;
    private int NR_OF_FULL_VIP;
    private int NR_OF_FREE_PASS;
    private int NR_OF_ONE_DAY;
    private int NR_OF_ONE_DAY_VIP;
    private int TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE;

    private FestivalGate gate;

    public FestivalStatisticsThread(FestivalGate gate) {
        this.gate = gate;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        calculateNumberOfEachTicketType();
        calculateNumberOfPeople();
        showStats();
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private void calculateNumberOfEachTicketType() {
        synchronized (this.gate.getValidatedTickets()) {
            for (TicketType ticketType : this.gate.getValidatedTickets()) {
                if (ticketType.equals(TicketType.FULL)) {
                    NR_OF_FULL += 1;
                } else if (ticketType.equals(TicketType.FULL_VIP)) {
                    NR_OF_FULL_VIP += 1;
                } else if (ticketType.equals(TicketType.FREE_PASS)) {
                    NR_OF_FREE_PASS += 1;
                } else if (ticketType.equals(TicketType.ONE_DAY)) {
                    NR_OF_ONE_DAY += 1;
                } else if (ticketType.equals(TicketType.ONE_DAY_VIP)) {
                    NR_OF_ONE_DAY_VIP += 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    private void calculateNumberOfPeople() {
        TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE +=
                NR_OF_FULL +
                        NR_OF_FULL_VIP +
                        NR_OF_FREE_PASS +
                        NR_OF_ONE_DAY +
                        NR_OF_ONE_DAY_VIP
        ;
    }

    public void showStats() {
        System.out.println(
                TOTAL_NUMBER_OF_PEOPLE + " people have entered " + "\n" +
                        NR_OF_FULL + " have full tickets " + "\n" +
                        NR_OF_FREE_PASS + " have free passes " + "\n" +
                        NR_OF_FULL_VIP + " have full vip passes " + "\n" +
                        NR_OF_ONE_DAY + " have one day passes " + "\n" +
                        NR_OF_ONE_DAY_VIP + " have one day vip passes"
        );
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("-----------------------------------------------------------");
    }


}
```

Comment: Joining the Thread after start will stop executing for-loop until that thread is finished.

Comment: @Marvin if I don't use join not all types of tickets will be stored in the array

Answer (score 0):

To quote the [Oracle tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html):

> `t.join()` causes the current thread to pause execution until t's thread terminates

So effectively you are not making any real use of threading. On every pass through your `for` loop, you launch a thread but then wait for it to complete. No point in doing that, you could forgo the threads and just sequentially do your tasks’ work within the current thread.

---

In modern Java, we rarely need to address the `Thread` class directly. Instead we submit our `Runnable`/`Callable` task to an `ExecutorService`.

To schedule repeated calculations every 5 seconds, use a [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

```
ScheduledExecutorService ses = Executors. newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() ;
…
ses.scheduleAtFixedRate( myStatsCalcRunnable , 1 , 5 , TimeUnit.SECONDS ) ;
```

Caution: Be sure to eventually shut down your executor services. Otherwise their backing thread pools may continue running indefinitely, like a zombie ‍♂️.

Change this:

```
public class FestivalStatisticsThread extends Thread { … }
```

… with a `run` method into:

```
public class FestivalStatistics { … }
```

… with a `recalculate` method. Call that `recalculate` method from the `Runnable` task submitted to your scheduled executor service.

Or perhaps that functionality should just be a part of the `Gate` class. (I’m not sure. I’d have to think more on that.)

---

85,000 simultaneous threads may be too much of a burden on common hardware. Instead, start an executor service with a limited number of threads. Then submit your 85,000 tasks as `Runnable`/`Callable` objects. The executor service takes care of feeding those tasks to be executed on those limited number of threads.

In the future, if [*Project Loom*](https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/loom/Main) succeeds, you will be able to use 85,000 (or even millions) *virtual* threads (also known as “fibers”) at a time. To learn more, see the more recent talks by Ron Pressler or other members of the Loom team. Experimental builds based on early-access Java 18 are available now. The Loom team seeks feedback.

---

All of these topics have been addressed already on Stack Overflow.  Search to learn more. I myself have written multiple Answers with code examples, as have others.

---

By the way, I would make `FestivalGate` more encapsulated. The other classes should not have access to, or even know about, its internal use of a synchronized `List`. Add methods to collect and report on tickets.

---

Here is some quick code I wrote as a demonstration of topics discussed above.

Use at your own risk; I’ve not done any serious testing nor a thoughtful code review.

Perhaps I have oversimplified your domain problem. You could of course expand or rearrange as needed. But hopefully this shows clearly how to use executor service.

We have a basic `Ticket` class to represent each ticket. We use a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) here to define that class. We nest the enum of ticket types.

```java
package work.basil.festival;

import java.util.UUID;

public record Ticket( UUID id , Type type )
{
    enum Type
    { FULL_VIP, FREE_PASS, ONE_DAY, ONE_DAY_VIP }
}
```

We have a `Gate` class to hold our domain logic. We nest a `Statistics` class to hold our reported summary of tickets taken so far.

```java
package work.basil.festival;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.time.Instant;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Gate
{
    final private Set < Ticket > ticketsTaken;

    public Gate ( )
    {
        this.ticketsTaken = new HashSet <>();
    }

    synchronized public boolean takeTicket ( final Ticket ticket )
    {
        // Simulate hard work by sleeping some random amount of time.
        int millis = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( 2 );
        try { Thread.sleep( millis ); }catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        return this.ticketsTaken.add( ticket );
    }

    synchronized public List < Ticket > ticketsTaken ( )
    {
        return List.copyOf( this.ticketsTaken );  // Returns unmodifiable list of the `Ticket` objects contained in our private member set.
    }

    record Statistics( Instant when , int countTicketsTaken , Map < Ticket.Type, Integer > countOfTicketsTakenByType )
    {
    }

    synchronized public Statistics statistics ( )
    {
        int count = this.countTicketsTaken();
        Map < Ticket.Type, Integer > map = this.reportCountOfTicketsTakenByType();
        if ( count != map.values().stream().mapToInt( Integer :: intValue ).sum() ) { throw new IllegalStateException( "Counts do not match in Gate.Statistics. Error # 898e905f-9432-4195-a3e0-118bede2872d." ); }
        return new Statistics( Instant.now() , count , map );
    }

    private int countTicketsTaken ( )
    {
        return this.ticketsTaken.size();
    }

    private Map < Ticket.Type, Integer > reportCountOfTicketsTakenByType ( )
    {
        // We use `AtomicInteger` here not for thread-safety, but for the convenience of its `incrementAndGet` method.
        Map < Ticket.Type, AtomicInteger > map = new EnumMap < Ticket.Type, AtomicInteger >( Ticket.Type.class );
        Arrays.stream( Ticket.Type.values() ).forEach( type -> map.put( type , new AtomicInteger( 0 ) ) ); // Initialize the map, so each ticket-type has an atomic integer set to zero.
        this.ticketsTaken.stream().forEach( ticket -> map.get( ticket.type() ).incrementAndGet() );

        // Convert the AtomicInteger values to simply `Integer` values.
        Map < Ticket.Type, Integer > result = map.entrySet().stream().collect( Collectors.toMap( Map.Entry :: getKey , atomicInteger -> atomicInteger.getValue().intValue() ) );
        return Map.copyOf( result ); // Return an unmodifiable map, as a good practice.
    }
}
```

And we have an `App` class to drive a demonstration.

```java
package work.basil.festival;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.UUID;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

/**
 * Hello world!
 */
public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Hello World!" );

        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        final List < Ticket > ticketsToTake = this.generateTicketsForFestival();

        Gate gate = new Gate();

        // Report every five seconds on the progress of our gate taking tickets.
        ScheduledExecutorService reportingExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        reportingExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate( ( ) -> System.out.println( gate.statistics() ) , 0 , 5 , TimeUnit.SECONDS );

        ExecutorService ticketTakingExecutorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 7 );
        for ( Ticket ticket : ticketsToTake )
        {
            ticketTakingExecutorService.submit( ( ) -> gate.takeTicket( ticket ) );
        }
        ticketTakingExecutorService.shutdown();
        try { ticketTakingExecutorService.awaitTermination( 10 , TimeUnit.MINUTES ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }
        reportingExecutorService.shutdown();
        try { reportingExecutorService.awaitTermination( 10 , TimeUnit.MINUTES ); } catch ( InterruptedException e ) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        System.out.println( "« FIN » " + gate.statistics() );
    }

    private List < Ticket > generateTicketsForFestival ( )
    {
        List < Ticket > tickets = new ArrayList <>();
        for ( int i = 0 ; i < 85_000 ; i++ )
        {
            tickets.add(
                    new Ticket(
                            UUID.randomUUID() ,  // Randomly generate a UUID, to identify uniquely each ticket.
                            Ticket.Type.values()[ ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( Ticket.Type.values().length ) ]  // Randomly pick one of the ticket types.
                    )
            );
        }
        return List.copyOf( tickets );
    }
}
```

When run on an 8-core M1 MacBook Pro.

```
Hello World!
Statistics[when=2021-11-14T02:28:52.746596Z, countTicketsTaken=0, countOfTicketsTakenByType={FREE_PASS=0, ONE_DAY=0, ONE_DAY_VIP=0, FULL_VIP=0}]
Statistics[when=2021-11-14T02:28:57.800514Z, countTicketsTaken=7517, countOfTicketsTakenByType={FREE_PASS=1862, ONE_DAY=1953, ONE_DAY_VIP=1889, FULL_VIP=1813}]
Statistics[when=2021-11-14T02:29:02.804886Z, countTicketsTaken=15128, countOfTicketsTakenByType={FREE_PASS=3791, ONE_DAY=3788, ONE_DAY_VIP=3775, FULL_VIP=3774}]
Statistics[when=2021-11-14T02:29:07.746712Z, countTicketsTaken=22819, countOfTicketsTakenByType={FREE_PASS=5764, ONE_DAY=5653, ONE_DAY_VIP=5703, FULL_VIP=5699}]
Statistics[when=2021-11-14T02:29:12.769943Z, countTicketsTaken=30577, countOfTicketsTakenByType={FREE_PASS=7687, ONE_DAY=7631, ONE_DAY_VIP=7641, FULL_VIP=7618}]
Statistics[when=2021-11-14T02:29:17.803627Z, countTicketsTaken=38146, countOfTicketsTakenByType={FREE_PASS=9553, ONE_DAY=9552, ONE_DAY_VIP=9554, FULL_VIP=9487}]
Statistics[when=2021-11-14T02:29:22.785355Z, countTicketsTaken=45896, countOfTicketsTakenByType={FREE_PASS=11455, ONE_DAY=11497, ONE_DAY_VIP=11499, FULL_VIP=11445}]
Statistics[when=2021-11-14T02:29:27.768809Z, countTicketsTaken=53563, countOfTicketsTakenByType={FREE_PASS=13448, ONE_DAY=13393, ONE_DAY_VIP=13386, FULL_VIP=13336}]
Statistics[when=2021-11-14T02:29:32.739398Z, countTicketsTaken=61189, countOfTicketsTakenByType={FREE_PASS=15358, ONE_DAY=15291, ONE_DAY_VIP=15310, FULL_VIP=15230}]
Statistics[when=2021-11-14T02:29:37.751764Z, countTicketsTaken=68758, countOfTicketsTakenByType={FREE_PASS=17214, ONE_DAY=17136, ONE_DAY_VIP=17226, FULL_VIP=17182}]
Statistics[when=2021-11-14T02:29:42.759303Z, countTicketsTaken=76446, countOfTicketsTakenByType={FREE_PASS=19136, ONE_DAY=19057, ONE_DAY_VIP=19171, FULL_VIP=19082}]
Statistics[when=2021-11-14T02:29:47.768858Z, countTicketsTaken=84030, countOfTicketsTakenByType={FREE_PASS=21086, ONE_DAY=20930, ONE_DAY_VIP=21062, FULL_VIP=20952}]
« FIN » Statistics[when=2021-11-14T02:29:48.406351Z, countTicketsTaken=85000, countOfTicketsTakenByType={FREE_PASS=21321, ONE_DAY=21174, ONE_DAY_VIP=21305, FULL_VIP=21200}]
```